# How to connect test database in functional testing?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I study functional test in symfony and It was really successful working on it, but I have problem in the database. In my system, I have 2 database, sample database and sample_test database. The sample database is for production and sample_test for testing for functional test. I have empty data in sample_test. In my config_test.yml.

```
doctrine:
    # ...
    dbal:
        host:     127.0.1.1
        dbname:   sample_test
        user:     root
        password: null
```

If I load my fixture. It successfully added to my sample_test database. When doing a functional test to my code. How can I connect it to my sample_test database? Just like this code

```
public function testAddPatient(){

    $values = array(
        'patient' => array(
            'company' => 1,
            'profile' => array(
                'firstName' => 'John',
                'lastName' => 'Funtional test',
                'email' => 'email123@gmail.com',
                'gender' => 1,
                'address' => array(
                    'street' => 'test functional street',
                    'zipCode' => 122,
                    'city' => 367,
                    'state' => 194,
                    'country' => 235
                )
            ),
            'medicalProfile' => array(
                'policyNumber' => 11
            )
        )
    );

    $this->client->request('POST', '/api/v1/patients', $values, array(), array( 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'));

    $this->assertEquals(
        Response::HTTP_OK,
        $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()
    );
}
```

When I add the patient. It supposed to be added in my sample_test database not in sample database. Did I miss something about the setup of my database or config? This is the last step I have now to finish my project.

when I run the command `phpunit` it doesn't add to sampte_test database

**Additional Info:**

This is what happened to my setup
I copy app_dev.php and convert it to app_test.php. I did some changes on that file. I export the data and structure in sample database and import it to sample_test database. **NOTE:** I edit the redirect_uris in oath_clients table, just replace dev to test. In my webtestcase controller I have this code

```
public function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient(array(),
            array(
                'PHP_AUTH_USER' => self::USERNAME,
                'PHP_AUTH_PW' => self::PASSWORD
            ));

    }
```

since the username and password is my sample_test database now. When I run phpunit. It works now.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html#creating-a-new-environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work out of the box as expected, as the Kernel created by Symfony `WebTestCase` is by default loaded with env = test.

You can manually override the environment using the `options` argument of `WebTestCase::createClient()` or by setting an environment variable. See: https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Test/KernelTestCase.php#L82

You should check your `createClient()` call. Try also to set the env  explicitly:

```
$client = static::createClient(array(
    'environment' => 'test',
    'debug'       => false,
));
```

To investigate further:

1. Find out which env is used inside the controller. Either use a debugger or print out `$this->container->get('kernel')->getEnvironment();`
2. If your in `dev`: Check your db queries. Do they explicitly add the database-name as in `INSERT INTO sample.tablename ...`

Comment: I add that code but It doesn't work. What other config did you do to work for it? after I run the phpunit command. It doesn't work

Comment: It add to my sample database not in sample_test database.

Comment: but when I echo this $this->client->getContainer()->get('kernel')->getEnvironment(); I get the result test which correct

Comment: What was the cause? You should add a comment or add an answer yourself if its not related to my answer. Otherwise this is not of much help for other SO users.

Comment: I add additional info in my post

Answer (score 1):

In your `web` directory you can find access files from 2 environment, prod (app.php), dev (app_dev.php)
If you want you config_test.yml apply you should create third env file, app_test.php which will pass 'test' into AppKernel object

You can also do it on dev env but then you should add some http header in each of your functional test to let symfony know its a test and switch database (but as I said, first option should do the job)

Comment: hello kam. I already create app_test.php then when I run this command vendor/bin/phpunit. It doesn't add to my sample_test database. do I miss something

Comment: thanks for this idea. It really helps me a lot. thanks again. :)